# MVC 5 does a controller exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, exists

I am coding an MVC 5 internet application and wish to know if it is possible to check if a `controller` `exists` where I only have the `name` of the `controller`?

I have a `Application_Error` function that gets the name of the `controller` when an error occurs, and I wish to redirect to the index method of the `controller`. The problem is that a user can enter in a `controller` name that does not exist, and redirecting to this `controller` results in an endless loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tempRequestContext = new RequestContext(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext, 
                                            new RouteData());
tempRequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Area"] = "";
tempRequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = "YourCompany.Controllers";
var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()
            .CreateController(tempRequestContext, "ControllerName");

if(controller != null)
{
   //TODO: Redirect
}
```

Comment: Currently, if the controller does not exist, I am getting an exception. Is the only way to check if a controller does not exist to check if an exception is thrown?

Comment: All I have changed from your code is to replace "ControllerName" with the desired controller name. Is this all that needs to be done?

Comment: You also need to change the namespace

Comment: No controller should be either null when it does not exists or contain the controller, you set the area too? What exception are you getting?

Comment: System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The controller for path '/knaklsdnlsda' was not found or does not implement IController.